# How can I convert Date JsonObject to String?

Tags: symfony4, angular9

I want to get the date from an API written with Symfony 4 to Angular 9 but the Json object is in this form what can I do to convert it to string?
Please help!

```
offset: 7200
timestamp: 1597960800
timezone: {name: "Europe/Berlin", transitions: Array(144), location: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JSON object is stored in a variable named `dateJson`, you can convert this date JSON object to a date string (using timestamp) with this JavaScript code:

```js
// We multiply timestamp by 1000 because JavaScript use milliseconds.
var date = new Date(dateJson.timestamp * 1000);
var dateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(dateString);
```